# Integral domains with finitely many units

Tags: reference-request, ac.commutative-algebra

> Question: Is there a classification of (noetherian if needed) integral domains with finitely many units ? (of course we can exclude fields as trivial examples)

Probably there are many such domains that I can not think of but maybe there is an overview article of what is known.

If it helps one can also assume some additional things like characteristic 0.

Comment: My guess is that if you choose a random ideal $I\leq R=\mathbb{Z}[x_1,\dotsc,x_n]$ with not too many generators, then $R/I$ will usually be an integral domain with $(R/I)^\times=\{1,-1\}$.  If so, then there is no hope of a classification.

Comment: This could be interesting to you: https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.02341

Comment: Note:  if $R \rightarrow S$ has finite kernel and finite cokernel then the same is true for $R^* \rightarrow S^*$.